# Code occasionally autocorrects to lowercase letters when it seems it shouldn't

Tags: excel, vba

Occasionally, VBA autocorrects code I have written with upper case letters to lower case letters. This seems to happen the most with the letters `C` and `R`, though in very specific circumstances.

For example, VBA likes to autocorrect `[C1].Value` to `[c1].Value`, whilst `.Row` frequently autocorrects to `.row`. These are two phrases I have used frequently in a project at the moment and consistently autocorrect.

However, typing `.Count`, for example, does not result in a correction. As for `R`, I'm afraid I can't think of an equivalent example...

Is there a clear reason why VBA does this? My results never seem to be affected by these corrections, though I wonder if there are any situations where there would be a clear difference between `.Row` and `.row`.

Comment: That usually means that you have used those as variables somewhere.

Comment: It generally means that you have previously used `row` as a procedure/variable/object name.

Comment: VBA (the language itself) is case-insensitive - the editor typically auto-corrects `row` to `Row` (when used as a property/method etc of an object) but it's not required for your code to run correctly.

Comment: Thank you all for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truth be told, it doesn't really matter, **because [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) is case insensitive**.

- So `expression.Row` and `expression.row` are evaluated the same thing
- As to why, as others pointed out in the comments, it's most likely because you used a variable/procedure/object/module/class/userform with the same name (eg. `row`, but lowercase) - which in itself is not the best programming practice and should be avoided if possible.
- Additionally an important note to make, **if you declared something with lowercase, it will  persist auto-correcting to lowercase even after you remove the declaration**. *(Sigh.. thank you Microsoft).* To fix this behaviour, re-declare the *variable (or something else)* with upper-case and then remove the declaration again.